# Error connecting to Microsoft SQL Server in IBM IIB via JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc, ibm-integration-bus

I cannot connect to Microsoft SQL Server v. 2008 in Websphere IIB (formerly, Message Broker) with a JDBC provider.
I've created the provider according to the IBM documentation - [Setting up a JDBC provider for type 4 connections](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ah61310_.htm) and specified a valid security identity.
I've also tried using the latest versions of sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc41.jar from Microsoft.

I'm trying to get the connection using:

```
Connection conn = getJDBCType4Connection(THE_NAME_OF_THE_PROVIDER,JDBC_TransactionType.MB_TRANSACTION_AUTO)
```

I get the following error trace:

```
Exception details:  message: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError stack trace: [java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:259) 
javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(Unknown Source) 
com.ibm.jsse2.lb.g(lb.java:44) 
com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:108) 
com.ibm.jsse2.l$c_.a(l$c_.java:6) 
com.ibm.jsse2.l.a(l.java:80) 
com.ibm.jsse2.m.a(m.java:15) 
com.ibm.jsse2.m.h(m.java:13) 
com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:38) 
com.ibm.jsse2.qc.<init>(qc.java:632) 
com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:16) 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1606) 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1324) 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:992) 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:828) 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:629) 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.createNewConnection(SQLServerPooledConnection.java:60) 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.<init>(SQLServerPooledConnection.java:42) 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXAConnection.<init>(SQLServerXAConnection.java:30) 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource.getXAConnection(SQLServerXADataSource.java:51) 
com.ibm.broker.jdbctype4.jdbcdbasemgr.JDBCType4Connection.createXAConnection(JDBCType4Connection.java:244) 
com.ibm.broker.jdbctype4.jdbcdbasemgr.JDBCType4DatabaseManager.getThreadOwnedConnections(JDBCType4DatabaseManager.java:308) 
com.ibm.broker.jdbctype4.localtrxn.JDBCType4SinglePhaseTrxnHandler.getConnection(JDBCType4SinglePhaseTrxnHandler.java:262) 
com.ibm.broker.jdbctype4.localtrxn.JDBCType4SinglePhaseTrxnHandler.getConnection(JDBCType4SinglePhaseTrxnHandler.java:154) 
com.ibm.broker.jdbctype4.connfact.JDBCType4ConnectionFactory.getConnection(JDBCType4ConnectionFactory.java:163) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94) 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619) 
com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbNode.getJDBCType4Connection(MbNode.java:1575) 
ru.cinimex.fr2back.FR2BACK_DB_InsertMessage_JavaCompute.fillInCache(FR2BACK_DB_InsertMessage_JavaCompute.java:115) 
ru.cinimex.fr2back.FR2BACK_DB_InsertMessage_JavaCompute.createCache(FR2BACK_DB_InsertMessage_JavaCompute.java:102) 
ru.cinimex.fr2back.FR2BACK_DB_InsertMessage_JavaCompute.evaluate(FR2BACK_DB_InsertMessage_JavaCompute.java:38) 
com.ibm.broker.javacompute.MbRuntimeJavaComputeNode.evaluate(MbRuntimeJavaComputeNode.java:339) 
com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbNode.evaluate(MbNode.java:1491)
```

I think the SQL server driver is trying to use SSL which comes into a conflict with IBM's Java. Is there a way to prevent it from using SSL at all?

When I'm doing the same thing with an Oracle database, everything works well.
It's a requirement to use JDBC and not IIB's native ODBC drivers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the Microsoft JDBC Driver's use of SSL, it should be possible to do so by setting the "encrypt" data source property to a value of false.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb879920%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

The above would apply if you were programmatically creating & configuring the data source.  In the case where there is intermediate code handling that, it's likely there would be somewhere to specify name/value pairs of data source properties, for example, in data source configuration or on an API that you are using.  Is there anywhere that you have the opportunity to do that?  If this were a WebSphere Application Server data source, it would either be in data source custom properties (traditional) or properties.microsoft.sqlserver element nested under dataSource in server.xml (Liberty).